# Why am I getting error while creating dropdownlist in one column of jqxgird?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

I have created one grid using jqWidget. I'm trying to put the drop-down list in the 7th column of jqxgrid. My code is as follows. I can't get the expected output.

```
// Data which I want to get in dropdownlist
var drpSource = [
        { id: 1, name: "Edit" },
        { id: 2, name: "SendMail" }
];

// This is particular 'column' part of my grid
 columns: [
                { dataField: 'user_name', text: 'Username', },
                { dataField: 'first_name', text: 'First Name', },
                { dataField: 'last_name', text: 'Last Name', },
                { dataField: 'email', text: 'Email', width: 300 },
                { dataField: 'register_dt', text: 'Registered Date', cellsformat: 'MM/dd/yyyy', },
                { dataField: 'expiration_dt', text: 'Expiry Date', cellsformat: 'MM/dd/yyyy', },
                {
                    width: 100, autoshowfiltericon: false, dataField: 'drpfunction',  text: "Function", columntype: 'dropdownlist',
                    createeditor: function (row, cellvalue, editor) {
                            editor.jqxDropDownList({
                            source: drpSource,
                            displayMember: 'name',
                            valueMember: 'id',
                            filterable: false,
                            placeHolder: 'Choose…',
                            autoDropDownHeight: true
                        });
                    },
                     initeditor: function (row, cellvalue, editor) { 
                         editor.jqxDropDownList('selectItem', cellvalue);
                     }
                 }
```

Am I missing anything?

**Note: Column has been created successfully, Although it's blank.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mentioned what is your expected output and what error you received. I can't help you more without more info. Your code seems fine to me except you need to add `cellvaluechanging` event in order to change the id number displayed after you select the option in `jqxDropDownList`.

Also I think is good to mention that you need to double click the cell in column 7 in order to trigger the `jqxDropDownList`.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/f0szowah/ (You need to modify it to fit your case!)

html code:

```
<div id="jqxgrid"></div>
```

JavaScript + jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Data which I want to get in dropdownlist
    var drpSource = [
        { id: 1, name: "Edit" },
        { id: 2, name: "SendMail" }
    ];
    
    var data = [
        { user_name: "User1", first_name: "First1", last_name: "Last1", email: "email1@example.com", register_dt: "01/01/2024", expiration_dt: "01/01/2025", drpfunction: 1 },
        { user_name: "User2", first_name: "First2", last_name: "Last2", email: "email2@example.com", register_dt: "02/01/2024", expiration_dt: "02/01/2025", drpfunction: 2 },
        // Add more data as needed
    ];

    var source =
    {
        localdata: data,
        datatype: "array"
    };

    var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

    // This is particular 'column' part of my grid
    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
        width: 850,
        source: dataAdapter,
        pageable: true,
        autoheight: true,
        sortable: true,
        altrows: true,
        enabletooltips: true,
        editable: true,
        selectionmode: 'multiplecellsadvanced',
        columns: [
            { text: 'Username', datafield: 'user_name', width: 60 },
            { text: 'First Name', datafield: 'first_name', width: 80 },
            { text: 'Last Name', datafield: 'last_name', width: 80 },
            { text: 'Email', datafield: 'email', width: 150 },
            { text: 'Registered Date', datafield: 'register_dt', cellsformat: 'MM/dd/yyyy', width: 90 },
            { text: 'Expiry Date', datafield: 'expiration_dt', cellsformat: 'MM/dd/yyyy', width: 90 },
            { text: "Function", datafield: 'drpfunction', width: 80, columntype: 'dropdownlist',
              createeditor: function (row, cellvalue, editor) {
                  editor.jqxDropDownList({
                      source: drpSource,
                      displayMember: 'name',
                      valueMember: 'id',
                      filterable: false,
                      placeHolder: 'Choose…',
                      autoDropDownHeight: true
                  });
              },
              initeditor: function (row, cellvalue, editor) { 
                  editor.jqxDropDownList('selectItem', cellvalue);
              },
              cellvaluechanging: function (row, datafield, columntype, oldvalue, newvalue) {
                  if (newvalue != oldvalue) {
                      var item = drpSource.find(function(element) {
                          return element.name == newvalue;
                      });
                      if (item) {
                          return item.id;
                      }
                  } else {
                      return oldvalue;
                  }
              }
           }
        ]
    });
});
```